# Return rest api response as object

Tags: typescript

I need to solve a simple task - send get(post, put, delete) request, and return entire response as method output (Object should have property: response code, body, status, headers.. ...).
Using typecript and web-request or request. I am not sure I understand how promise or async/await works. Please help!

Signature of method should be:

```
get(url: string): Response{
  let response: Response = await WebRequest.get(url);
  return response;
}
```

This code is used for rest api testing. So validation would be on another layer. I just need to return the response.

Thanks in advance

[Update]

I have solved issue by creating async methods and then in jasmine use  async as well:
my method:

```
  async get(): Promise<WebRequest.Response<string>> {
    return await WebRequest.get('http://www.google.com/invalid');
  }
```

my test body:

```
it('test base http', async function () {
    expect(200).toBe(await client.get().statusCode);
});
```

For me it is a very dirty solution, as I need always care about async await keywords, and return Promise each time.

Any suggestion how to solve?

Comment: We won't write the code for you. Please show what you tried so far. And also add what you are getting and what you are expecting

Comment: I have jasmine based angine to run
desc
    it('test base http', () => {
        
        baseClient.get();
        expect(200).toBe(200);
    });

});

And class I am writing method.

export class BaseHttpClient {
 
  async get() { //should return response as it is ....
    log.info("start get request 111111");

      let response = await WebRequest.put('https://www.mydriver.com/en');
      log.info(response.content);
      return response;
  }

@rollstuhlfahrer I have tried really a lot .... for now I  see it was junk, not sure I need post all attempt here